# Bash script to Split a file into n files with each file containing x number of records

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a requirement where I need write a bash script to split a single input file into 'n' files and each file should not contain more than 'x' number of records (except the last file as the last file will have everything remaining). Values of 'n' and 'x' will be passed to the script as arguments by the user.

n should be the total number of split files

x should be the maximum number of records in a split file (except the last file).

Suppose if the input file has 5000 records and the user passes argument values of n and x as 3 and 1000 then, file 1 and 2 should contain 1000 records each and file 3 should contain 3000 records.
Another example will be if the input file has 4000 records and the user passes argument values of n and x as 2 and 3000 then, file 1 should contain 3000 records and file 2 should contain 1000 records.

I tried the below command:

```
split -n$maxBatch -l$batchSize --numeric-suffixes $fileDir/$nzbnListFileName $splitFileName
```

But it throws an error that, split cannot be done in more than one way.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

you either need to give -n parameter or -l parameter. not both of them together.

```
split -l1000 --numeric-suffixes yourFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like split isn't enough for your requirements then - it can do either files of X lines each, or N files, but not the combination. Try something like this:

```
awk -v prefix=$splitFileName -v lines=$x -v maxfiles=$n '
 (NR - 1) % lines == 0 && fileno < maxfiles { fileno +=1 }
 { print >> prefix fileno }' input.txt
```

That increments a counter every X lines up to N times, and writes lines to a file whose name depends on the counter.